# CakePHP how to validate CSRF token?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am using cakephp version 4, Here I have added csrf in middleware.

```
use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;

public function middleware(MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue): MiddlewareQueue
{
        $csrf = new CsrfProtectionMiddleware();
        $middlewareQueue->add($csrf)
        return $middlewareQueue;
}
```

In inspector element I am seeing token in hidden field. Now How I will validate it ? or It's already validated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already being validated your form, if not validate  then form validate would give an error

[image]